# Is it possible to use SHA1 in Lua Redis?

Tags: lua, redis, sha1

I have a Lua script in Redis that uses the `cjson` library, but then I need to create a SHA1 from it.

Is this possible or is there any complete documentation about what libraries are provided natively through the Lua Redis binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cjson is supported natively in Redis. To compute a SHA1 from a Lua script you can use `redis.sha1hex`. You will find the documentation [here](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL).